# Simple Hello World servlet can't run (Status 404)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm using Eclipse neon, Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu, and I'm trying a totally simple Hello world servlet. On the tutorial it is working but I get HTTP status 404.

I have tried it with and without web.xml but it is still same, and the web.xml is not automatically updated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post links to images. Post a clear description of the problem with sufficient code (as text) for reproducing/understanding what's happening.

Comment: You use annotation or XML configuration for servlet mapping?